# How to Detect new Microsoft browser "Edge" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, browser

In asp.net, using this construct, how might I detect the new Microsoft "Edge" browser?

```
    Dim wrkBrowser As String = ""
    Dim wrkBrowserType As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type
    If InStr(wrkBrowserType, "Chrome") <> 0 Then
        wrkBrowser = "Chrome"
    End If
    If InStr(wrkBrowserType, "MSIE") <> 0 Then
        wrkBrowser = "IE"
    End If
    If InStr(wrkBrowserType, "FireFox") <> 0 Then
        wrkBrowser = "FF"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an adept in anything .NET, but reading your code, it seems to me that the value returned by

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type
```

Is a user agent.

You can find information about the user-agent for Edge at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx) page.

User-agent for edge:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0

Note that the value can change based on mobile, xbox, etc.

So in your case, try doing a check on "Edge"

Comment: Great research, several things to think about;  thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I know the answer is a little late but I searched all over the place and never found this and had to write it myself.  The following code will allow the Request.Browser variables to return Edge and Edge Version instead of Chrome.

Adding the following snippet to a .browser file such as platform.browser in the App_Browsers folder will cause it to return Edge and the version.

```
<browser id="Edge" parentID="Chrome">
  <identification>
    <userAgent match="Edge/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+))" />
  </identification>
  <capabilities>
    <capability name="browser" value="Edge" />
    <capability name="version" value="${version}" />
    <capability name="majorversion" value="${major}" />
    <capability name="minorversion" value="${minor}" />
  </capabilities>
</browser>
```

Comment: Does creating an App_Browsers folder and adding this file extend .NETs existing list of browsers, or does this need to include all browsers you want to detect?
Is there another way to keep .NETs list of browsers up to date?

Comment: @RichardGarside it simply extends the existing list of browsers (see [MSDN Browser Definition File Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Please note that the above solution does not have consistent browser detection behavior! This is not because the the definition is incorrect per se, but because ASP.NET internally caches the detected browsers using only the first 64 characters of the user agent string, which is not unique between Chrome and Edge (and Safari on Windows, which probably very few people use). Whichever browser visits your site first will cause the others to be detected as the first.  To fix this, add a web.config entry:    <system.web><browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256" /></system.web>

Comment: Here is a great article about browser identification in ASP.NET https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088703/How-to-detect-browsers-in-ASP-NET-with-browser-fil

Answer (score 4):

As Joey mentioned, the User Agent string is what you want to look at. The properties of Request.Browser don't contain anything specific to Edge, but you can get the user agent string with HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent and use .IndexOf("Edge") to search it.

Comment: And in case you want to do something with the version, you could get it like this:

`HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string version = 
req.UserAgent.Substring(req.UserAgent.IndexOf("Edge") + 5);`

Answer (score 1):

on Windows NT 10.0 Microsoft Edge, Request.UserAgent as below and not **Edge**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.66
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the UserAgent like this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(HttpContext.Request.UserAgent, @"Edge\/\d+"))
{
    wrkBrowser = "Edge"
}
```

If you're checking for multiple browsers be careful of the order you check as many browsers like to mention other browsers in their UserAgent string.

This is Edge's current User Agent String:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.DefaultIfEmpty().Contains("Edge")

DefaultIfEmpty() is an extension method I wrote that ensures empty string if the string is null.

Comment: I prefer string comparison over Regex for readablility and simpler modification. If the comparison becomes a pattern I would switch to Regex.

Answer (score 0):

For browser compatibility you can use this code. This method returns browser name and version :

```
private string GetBrowserNameWithVersion
{
    var userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
    var browserWithVersion = "";
    if (userAgent.IndexOf("Edge") > -1)
    {
        //Edge
        browserWithVersion = "Edge Browser Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "Edge/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
    }
    else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Chrome") > -1)
    {
        //Chrome
        browserWithVersion = "Chrome Browser Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "Chrome/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
    }
    else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Safari") > -1)
    {
        //Safari
        browserWithVersion = "Safari Browser Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "Safari/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
    }
    else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Firefox") > -1)
    {
        //Firefox
        browserWithVersion = "Firefox Browser Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "Firefox/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
    }
    else if (userAgent.IndexOf("rv") > -1)
    {
        //IE11
        browserWithVersion = "Internet Explorer Browser Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "rv:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
    }
    else if (userAgent.IndexOf("MSIE") > -1)
    {
        //IE6-10
        browserWithVersion = "Internet Explorer Browser  Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "MSIE" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];                
    }
    else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Other") > -1)
    {
        //Other
        browserWithVersion = "Other Browser Version : " + userAgent.Split(new string[] { "Other" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
    }

    return browserWithVersion;

}
```

Comment: Edg is another string.    Below is an example and Edg is shown.  Not sure why mine does not have Edge.
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.78"