# Getting incorrect browser name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following code snippet

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
   var browser = Request.Browser;

   if(browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer") {
      //logic here
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on `var browser = Request.Browser;` and visit the application from Microsoft Edge browser then instead of the browser name being `Edge` I get `Chrome` as you can see in the below image. Can someone tell me why this happens?

The application is written in C# and Asp.Net MVC

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how is this being handled by ASP platform, however when You are receiving HTTP request (GET HTTP/1.1), most browser includes also rendering core (e.g. Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 ) [Refer to USER_AGENT](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending). I believe this might be the reason why You've got there Chrome as edge might be using Chrome's engine

Comment: Try searching. Something about capability files matching user agent strings with browser names. See also [check whether browser is chrome or edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870789/check-whether-browser-is-chrome-or-edge).

Comment: From MSDN: [User-agent string changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Trying to detect the browser is a *bad* idea that leads to frequent bugs if eg your code fails to detect newer browsers. MVC *already* uses the correct way to handle different browsers - detect capabilities instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to detect if the browser is IE and the verssion is less than 8. Then I want the user to see error page because the app does not support it

Comment: BTW your image shows a `Browsers` property with 4 items. That contains all browsers mentioned in the user agent string. `Browser` simply displays the first of them. It's *still* the wrong way to handle different browsers though

Comment: @Code that's not what you asked though. You'd get a *different* answer if you did, eg "Check for that specific user agent string or version"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was going to ask a separate question for that once I got the answer for this one